# jQuery finding children recursively, but ignore certain elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Lets assume the following HTML

```
<div id=main>
   <div id=a></div>
   <div id=b></div>
   <div id=c></div>
   <div id=d>
      <div id=d1 class="no">
        <div id=d11></div>
        <div id=d12></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id=e>
      <div id=e1 class="no">
        <div id=e11></div>
        <div id=e12></div>
        <div id=e13></div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I want to select all div tags that are children of main, but want to ignore children of divs that have a class as "no".

I have currently written a recursive function to do the job. But was wondering if there is a jQuery selector to get what I want.

I want the DIVs with ids a,b,c,d,d1,e,e1

Thanks

**EDIT**: Created a test page here - http://jsfiddle.net/mRENV/

Comment: So, did you mean **children** divs of main or **ancestor** divs of main?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a single selector with no further traversal you could do this:
[`$('#main div:not(div.no > div)');`](http://jsfiddle.net/k6Myh/)

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works the fastest - http://jsperf.com/finding-children-bug-ignoring-certain-children

Comment: @Arun: Just to explain the results: The first one is faster because of two resons: (a) You are using the child selector `>`. Without it, the difference is less ([see here](http://jsperf.com/finding-children-bug-ignoring-certain-children/2)) (b) In modern browsers, jQuery can make use of `querySelectorAll` and pass a valid CSS selector directly. In older browser you probably see no difference.

Answer (score 12):

It should be:

```
$('#main div').not('.no div')
```

Btw. the term *children* only refers to the *direct* descendants of an element. You want to get all descendants (not only children) of `#main`.

**Reference:** [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

**Edit:** Updated your demo so that it works properly: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/mRENV/1/

Comment: Yes Felix, all descendants, not just immediate children. Please see here http://jsfiddle.net/mRENV/

Comment: @Arun: See my update. Your demo does not work properly because you are changing the content of the elements, which removes their children.

Comment: Thanks Felix, it works. But was wondering if me writing a recursive loop and ignoring elements with class .no is more efficient than asking jQuery to search for all children and THEN remove elements that are not required?

Comment: @Arun: I don't know. Probably. You can benchmark your code at http://jsperf.com/. Create two test cases and see which one is faster. You should also add `div`'s that are outside of `#main`.

Answer (score 4):

Several syntactical ways to achieve that using jQuery, my suggestion is:

```
var $result = $('#main').find('div:not(.no > div)');
```

Invoking [`.find()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) along with the pseudo [`:not()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector. This line is equivalent to:

```
var $result = $('#main').find('div').not('.no > div');
```

while the latter might be slightly faster.

Comment: I made the same mistake. This will ignore all `.no` elements, but actually he wants to ignore all descendants of `.no` elements.